# Rails: How can I parse an RSS file with Feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedjira

I'm trying to parse an RSS file. It throws a 404 response when I do:

```
Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url
```

So I thought trying:

```
Feedjira::Parser::RSS.parse url
```

But that returns 0 entries

This is exactly what I'm trying:

```
<% Feedjira::Parser::RSS.parse("my url here").entries.each do |e| %>

    <%= "#{e.title}" %><br />

<% end %>
```

The rss file is being parse with no problem with php in another web. This is the structure:

```
    <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>Title here</title>
            ... etc ...
            <item>
                <title>Title here</title>
                 ... etc ...
            </item>
            <item> ... etc ... </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

Comment: Can you provide the url, so that I can test it out myself?

Comment: @RahulRoy here is (see bellow)

Comment: The regular method, which I've used succesfully with ``<feed>`` files, throws with ``<rss>`` files this error: **Fetch failed - 404**.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me without any 404 error. I used the same `fetch_and_parse` method.

Comment: @RahulRoy Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @RahulRoy And if you say you got it working, why don't u post an answer with the code? That would be helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Sure https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tkly4atfr1fqi8/Screenshot%202015-06-18%2001.30.37.png?dl=0

Comment: Sure! Should I just undelete the old answer or just add a new one?

Comment: @RahulRoy Probably edit the old one.

Comment: @RahulRoy BTW I tried on the console like you did (according with the image linked from dropbox) and I had the same 404 response. I'm really looking forward to see if your code is different than mine, because if you can fetch with the same code that I can't, then I have a very different problem here. I'll give you the best answer anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to remove that url, as it contains your access token. Which needs to be secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird that `Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url` wasn't working for you. It's working perfectly fine for me.

Here's how I did it. I'm using Railscasts RSS feed for example purpose:

```
url = "http://railscasts.com/subscriptions/rZNfSBu1hH7hOwV1mjqyLw/episodes.rss"
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url

feed.entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry.title
end
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I'm trying to parse an RSS file. It throws a 404 response when I do: ``Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url``. It's the first thing I wrote.

Comment: @DaseinA My bad! Somehow I forgot the first part while trying out feedjira. Sorry for that :(

Comment: Are you sure you got it working with my **URL**? It keeps giving me the 404 response when I replace your url with mine. I'll award you with the best answer anyway because this seems to be a very different problem, rather related with IPs restrictions from my server or something. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It got it working from the same URL(the one provided by you). Can't you tell it from the output? Thanks for choosing my answer. I'm glad that it helped.